# AngularJs Service function- this()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I'm learning about angularjs and I keep noticing when a function is declared, most people usually make "this" into a var before modifying it. Why is that?

Code snippet below:

```
function NameService() {

     var self = this; **THIS BLOCK. WHY??**

    //getName returns a promise which when 
    //fulfilled returns the name.
    self.getName = function() {
      return $http.get('/api/my/name');
    };
}
```

And at the bottom, the example uses self.getName. Why not just directly call this.getName?

Thanks

Comment: it's a way to keep the correct 'this' value and avoid confusion. say you want to run  a method from a success function of a AJAX call, you'd use 'self' and not 'this', because this will not mean what you mean

Comment: Thank you. This makes perfect sense and impressed at how fast these replies came :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a pattern that you can use. Generally it helps avoiding collisions of the 'this' keyword which is very common in the javascript 'world'.

Also helps with readability, so you can easier read your code.
Check out this example, where you can easily distinguish the public functions of the service and the local/private ones:

```
function NameService() {

    var self = this; **THIS BLOCK. WHY??**

    self.getName = getName;
    self.setName = setName;


    //getName returns a promise which when 
    //fulfilled returns the name.
    function getName() {
        return $http.get('/api/my/name');
    };

    function setName(){
       //blablabla
    }

    function justAHelperFunction(){
        //helper function, kind of inner function, a private function
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!!. Now the rest of the code sample im looking at makes so much more sense. i was racking my brain for ~ an hour trying to figure it out.

Comment: I'm glad to help you figuring it out ;)

Answer (score 0):

In javascript `this` refers to the current object and the value of `this` in say a method depends how the function is invoked. When you pass a callback to a function call the context of `this` gets changed and inside the callback definition `this` doesn't refer to the object that has the method which further called the function with callback.

```
var person = {
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',

  printFullName: function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      // here this doesn't point to the person object anymore
      // as the callback passed to setTimeout was invoked by global window object
      // so this points to window
      console.log(this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName);
    }, 100)
  }
}
```

To fix the above scenario where you expect this to be person you make an alias of the context capturing the reference in another variable. Here's the correct version of above method.

```
printFullName: function () {
    var self = this;
    // till now self == this
    setTimeout(function () {
      // here self still points to person whereas this is now pointing to window
      console.log(self.firstName + ' ' + self.lastName);
    }, 100)
  }
```